# Angular - How to redirect login to dashboard based on roles from API response

Tags: angular

I am using Angular-11 and Laravel-8, Laravel-Passport and Laravel-Spatie-Permission for HRM project. I have this JSON response from user Login:

```js
{
  "message": "Successfully Logged In.",
  "error": false,
  "code": 200,
  "results": {
    "user": {
      "id": 2,
      "username": "Lamptey",
      "email": "lamptey@gmail.com",
      "mobile_number": "2318056785544",
      "first_name": "Lamptey",
      "last_name": "Akwetey",
      "email_verified_at": null,
      "active": 1,
      "created_at": "2021-05-24T07:27:41.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2021-05-26T19:02:30.000000Z",
      "roles": [{
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Supervisor",
        "guard_name": "api",
        "created_at": "2021-05-24T07:02:14.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-05-24T07:02:14.000000Z",
        "pivot": {
          "model_id": 2,
          "role_id": 4,
          "model_type": "App\\Models\\User"
        }
      }],
      "employee": null
    },
    "access_token": {
      "id": "cggfgfgfggggggggggggggg",
      "user_id": 2,
      "client_id": 1,
      "name": "iHRM",
      "scopes": [],
      "revoked": false,
      "created_at": "2021-05-26 20:02:30",
      "updated_at": "2021-05-26 20:02:30",
      "expires_at": "2021-08-25T19:02:30.000000Z"
    },
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_at": "2021-08-25 20:02:30"
  }
}
```

auth-guard.service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router, ActivatedRoute, Route } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {


  constructor(private _router: Router,private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

    if (localStorage.getItem('user') != null && state.url == '/accounts/login') {
      this._router.navigate(['/supervisor-dashboard']);
      return true;
    }
    var userId;
     this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      var userId = params['id'];
    });
     var currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
     if(localStorage.getItem('user') != null){
     currentUser.permissions.forEach(element => {
     });
    }

    return true;
  }

}
```

authentication.service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
    public token: string;
    public ipAddress:string;
    private headers: HttpHeaders;
    private readonly apiUrl = environment.apiUrl;
    private readonly baseUrl = environment.baseUrl;
    user_id = '';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router,) {
        //append headers
        // set token if saved in local storage
        var currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
        this.token = currentUser && currentUser.token;
        if(this.token){
          this.user_id = currentUser.profile.user_id;
        }
    }

    login(email: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
        this.headers = new HttpHeaders();
        this.headers.append("Content-Type", 'application/json');
        this.headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        this.headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Authorization, Content-Type, Accept");
        return this.http.post(this.apiUrl+'/login', { email: email, password: password, ip: this.ipAddress }, { headers: this.headers } )
            .pipe(
                map((response: Response) => {
                    this.token = response['token'];
                    let email = response['email'];
                    if (this.token) {
                        localStorage.setItem('user',
                            JSON.stringify({ email: email, token: this.token, profile: response['profile'], info : response['ip_info'], permissions: response['permissions']}));
                    }
                    return response;
                })
            );
    }   
}
```

login.component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import { NgxSpinnerService } from 'ngx-spinner';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../../service/authentication.service';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  apiUrl = environment.apiUrl;
  email: string = '';
  password: string = '';
  email_validation: string = '';
  password_validation: string = '';
  response_error: string = '';
  errorMessage = '';
  saving= false;
    constructor(private spinner: NgxSpinnerService, private authService: AuthenticationService, private router: Router) {}
  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.spinner.show();
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.spinner.hide();
    }, 100);
  }
  onLogIn() {
    this.email_validation= '';
    this.password_validation = '';
    this.saving=true;
    this.authService.login(this.email, this.password)
    .subscribe(res => {
        this.saving=false;
        if(res['token']){
          window.location.reload();
        }
    }, error => {
      this.saving=false;
      this.email_validation= '';
      this.password_validation = '';
      this.response_error = '';
      if(error.error.email){
       this.email_validation = error.error.email;
      }
      else if(error.error.password){
       this.password_validation = error.error.password;
      }
      else{
       this.response_error = error.error;
      }
      console.error(error.error);
    });
  }
}
```

**The user logins in with username (email or phone) and password.**

**Roles: supervisor, hod, staff and admin.**

**Dashboards: supervisor-dashboard, hod-dashboard, staff-dashboard and admin-dashboard**

What I want to achieve is this:

After login, the application should redirect to appropriate dashboard based on the roles above from the api response.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can simply maintain constant object where key is role name or id, and its value say dashboard url, like

```
public static readonly DASHBOARD_ROUTE_PER_ROLES = 
{
    "supervisor" : "/supervisor-dashboard",
    "hod": "/hod-dashboard",
    "staff": "/staff-dashboard",
    "admin": "/admin-dashboard"
}
```

And when you read your response json, look for the role your logged in user has.

```
let userRole = roleFromJson;
this.route.navigate([userRole.toLowerCase()]);
```

// since the key is in lowercase

Hope you have understood.

Comment: Kindly pardon me. 1. Where do I add this in the code? 2. Secondly, any other role not stated here should go to dashboard.

Comment: @user11352561 Well, it is not a strict rule, but a good practice to maintain shared folder named "common" or "shared" inside your app folder, where you add your reusable components, helper class, utilities, models, etc. that can be used across your app. I generally place inside **app/common/utility/common-helper.ts**. There you can write a method that returns the url based on the role you pass. Use switch case default syntax to ensure that method returns default value in case no matching roles existed there.
Sorry for this long comment, :D